# Animation & Aiming in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, scripting

I'm working on a third person game. I have a scene with a character with animations on the Animator component. When starting the game, the character stands still and aims at a certain point. This was done using an "aiming" animation with just one frame.

Further, a script hangs on the character, which should carry out aiming.

```cs
using UnityEngine;


public class TestRotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform spin;
    [SerializeField] Vector2 sensinivity = new Vector2(1, 1);

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 axis;

        axis.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        axis.y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        spin.Rotate(axis.y * sensinivity.x, -axis.x * sensinivity.y, 0);

    }
}
```

That is, rotate the "spin" bone with the mouse. But as a result of starting the game on the stage, only the twitching of the character's hands is visible.

The "aiming" animation overwrites the rotation result of the "spin" bone.

**How can I make the aiming work and also play animations?**

For example, I want to add a recoil animation when fired. But any animation will overwrite the result of the "spin" rotation.

---

*UPDATE 1:*

I removed all animations and left the default state without any animation. But still, the script cannot rotate the bone "spin".

The animator still overwrites the changes made by the script.

**How can I make a script to rotate a bone with Animator enabled?**

---

*UPDATE 2:*

Made an experimental scene with an improvised hand. I animated the top, and rotated the hand with the script. It turned out to be a correct rotation. **Conclusion: a bone that is rotated using a script should not be affected by animation.**

**But how can I remove the effect of the animation imported from the fbx file on the rotated bone**, if the transformations there are not indicated by rotation, scale and position, since Unity has its own terminology for designating the transformations of animated objects?

**Where can I read about the terminology of animation in Unity?**

Answer (score 0):

If your animator state is staying at the default aim animation clip, you will not be able to control the bone unless you disable the animator. What you coold do is creating an empty state, so after you play the initial default aim animation, the animator transitions to the empty state, so you are able to control the rotitaion

Comment: I added a state without animation. After the transition into it, the character is move down to the midle and all the same, only the twitching of the hands is visible. Aiming still doesn't work. Turned off the animator and aiming started working. But I can't turn it off as I need character animations.

Comment: Maybe if you create two layers in the animator, one to control the body and the other to control the aim,  you can add a empty state to the aim layer and control it via script while the other layer keeps the body in position. Make the layers additional and with weight = 1 so both can work together

Comment: I disabled all animations and left the default state. I removed the animation from it. And the result is one default state without animation. But still, the character goes down (this is how the empty state affects him) and still, instead of aiming, I see only twitches. What then is the point of making an additional layer with an empty state?

Comment: Sorry, I might not be getting it. Maybe some images of the animation results would help me understand

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add a video. But I can explain. The animation simply overwrites the rotation of the bone that the script does. How can you combine the working the script and animation? Maybe you know a video tutorial showing how to do it.